# Kafka connect - file pulse - 'xml attribute' extraction

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use the file pulse connector to read XML file.
I am new to Kafka/Kafka Connect/XML processing

For file like below, I'd like to keep the data **"unit"**, and the **"string1", "string2"**.
currently, by default the processed payload drop them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <someField>someValue</someField>
    <anotherField-I-Forced-the-type-to-Array>
        <value unit="string1">123</value>
        <value unit="string2">456</value>
    </anotherField-I-Forced-the-type-to-Array>
    <lastField>lastValue</lastField>
</data>
```

**Does some kind of configruation already exist?**
I have not found the configuration in the doc https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/developer-guide/file-readers/

Please help and maybe give some examples if there are already solution exist.

currently I got this payload. You can see `unit` and its value `string1`, `string2` are gone.

```
"anotherField-I-Forced-the-type-to-Array": [
{
  "value": [
    "123",
    "456"
  ]
}
],
```

ps. The version I used is 1.5.2 downloaded zip from here https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse/releases

**curious**, based on this article: https://medium.com/streamthoughts/streaming-data-into-kafka-s01-e02-loading-xml-file-21b5e69c645
the playlist does have 'name' attribute' and it was not lost.
 `<playlist name="BestOfStarWars">`

Comment: this is how i fored the filed to be array ```force.array.on.fields=anotherField-I-Forced-the-type-to-Array```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI This is now fixed in 1.5.3 version very quickly